# Convert DAG whose transitive reduction is non-planar to a planar DAG with same transitive closure

Tags: graphs, planar-graphs

For any non-planar DAG, we can compute the transitive reduction, and sometimes it will be planar ([e.g. $K_5$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/88199/edge-removal-to-convert-a-non-planar-dag-to-a-planar-dag-while-maintaining-reach)).

However, sometimes the transitive reduction is also non-planar. For example, $K_{3, 3}$'s transitive reduction is just $K_{3, 3}$.

Alternatively, it's possible to add vertices and adjust the edges to maintain the same transitive closure as $K_{3,3}$, while producing a planar graph:

[image]

Here $U_{i}$ means "utility i" and $H_i$ means "house i", as per the [Three Utilities Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_utilities_problem).

Is there an algorithm that can accomplish this for a general DAG, so that the resulting graph is planar and can be used with [Thorup's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability#Thorup.27s_Algorithm)?